# Function takes a martix (2d array) and prints the max number of the even numbers in each line

Tags: java, arrays

I am defining a function to accept a matrix (2d array), for example `x[][]`; and the function should print the biggest even number in each line

```
public static void biggestEvenNumOfEachLine(int x[][]){
    int even,t=0,max;
    int arr[] = new int [x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length;j++,t++){
            if(x[i][j] % 2 == 0){
                even = x[i][j];
                arr[j] = even;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In general, we help people with specific problems they're having, but we don't tell them how to do things from the ground up. So, if you can edit your question to explain where you're getting confused or what isn't working, we can help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by finding the biggest even number in a single line array. Start with the smallest possible value, and then iterate the array. Test for even, and then set the `max` (and then return it). Something like,

```
private static int biggestEvenNum(int[] x) {
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {
            max = Math.max(max, x[i]);
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

**But**, in Java 8+, I would *prefer* to `filter` for even values and get the `max` like

```
private static int biggestEvenNum(int[] x) {
    return IntStream.of(x).filter(v -> v % 2 == 0).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Then your method is as simple as iterating the `line`(s) in your matrix, printing the result. Like,

```
public static void biggestEvenNumOfEachLine(int[][] x) {
    for (int[] line : x) {
        System.out.println(biggestEvenNum(line));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void biggestEvenNumOfEachLine(int x[][])
{
    int arr[] = new int [x.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length;i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < x[i].length;j++)
            if(x[i][j] % 2 == 0 && x[i][j] > arr[i]){
                arr[i] = x[i][j];
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
            }
}
```

This will work but if there is no even number at particular line then corresponding number to that line will be zero.

Comment: i shouldn't use methods like "Integer.MIN_VALUE  ,  Math.max"...i must define the all from the basic

Comment: Why can't  you use that methods? Math.max is easy to write it from scratch.

Comment: Yes ....but we learn the java basics ....this question from our professor and that question we must resolved without methods